# Netbeans color theming problem

Tags: colors, themes, netbeans-6.9

I'm trying to sort out my netbeans color theme and I'm almost there apart from one annoying highlight I can't seem to find anywhere! It only shows it self in HTML and CSS that I have seen so far!

Its the highlighting that happens when you click on an Id or class value for html elements, or elements in css

Have a look at the picture below and see if you can identify the option that defines the highlight below!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be the Cascading Style Sheet color for Mark Occurrences.

Tools|Options|Fonts & Colors, Select Language: Cascading Style Sheet, Select Category: Mark Occurrences.

It appears to be related to (but not exactly the same as) [NetBeans bug 189963](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189963), and may be worth noting on that bug that the highlight color suffers the same problem as the base color.

BTW, When I changed the color value for that one and clicked on OK, it did not immediately update the editor window. I had to select something else for it to mark occurrences of, and as soon as I did that I saw the new color.